# Excel plot chart from data as given in the example

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a huge spreadsheet with simple data as follows

```
13:04:28    A
13:04:37    A
13:06:56    B
13:07:03    B
13:07:10    C
13:07:18    C 
13:07:23    C 
13:07:28    C 
13:07:33    C
```

Basically timestamp,classification in two columns. i want to plot a pie chart showing the distribution of A,B and C etc by the number of times of their occurrence. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [countif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) function to count number of A,B,C and save numbers in other cells.
Finally you can use these values to plot your chart....

***[COUNTIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)(range,criteria) ---> for example the expression =COUNTIF(F:F,"A") gives number of "A" in your "F" column
Range    is the range of cells from which you want to count cells.
Criteria    is the criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that defines which cells will be counted. For example, criteria can be expressed as 32, "32", ">32", "apples", or B4.***

For more information you can see [Microsoft Office Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

You can also pivot your data, then choose a pie chart from one of your Pivot Chart options.  At least, I could in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should find the number of occurences for A, B, C, etc. individually. To do that, in a new column, enter the following formulae:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"=A")  
=COUNTIF(B:B,"=B")  
=COUNTIF(B:B,"=C")  
...
```

where B is the column where the values to be counted reside.

Then you can insert your pie-chart using those newly calculated values.